# Access 2013 Module in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: ms-access, taskscheduler

I have tried using Windows Task Scheduler to run my Access Database module although I can't figure out how to create the macro for this as I believe this is the only way to do this. 
The details I have are Program/script:`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"`Add Arguments(optional):`"C:\deskop\Reports.accdb" /x AutoExec` I have created a macro on my access database called AutoExec but I don't know how to call my module which is called Main.

My Module contains 5 different public functions and a Sub which I changed to Function. I have now added all 5 functions as RunCode and function name to the macro is this correct? it seems to be running the macro now.

Comment: You would want the macro to call a procedure, not a module. An easy way to achieve that, would be by opening a form, and have the form's `On Load` event handler call the desired Function or subroutine.

Comment: Macros can only call functions, not subs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in below steps

Step 1 : Create a macro (AutoExec in your case )  in database and call the function (main in your case).

Step 2:  Create a batch file, now in batch file you will write a code to open your database and call the macro that you want to execute (AutoExec)

e.g.

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" C:\AccessDatabase\MyDatabase.accdb /x:AutoExec)
```

When this batch file is exacuted, access database will be opened and AutoExec Macro from that database will run which inturn call your function and then complete the task that you want to do.

Step 3: in this step, create a scheduled task in Windows task scheduler. Create a new action as start a program and provide the above Step 2 created batch file path in Program/Script.

[image]

As per schedule you setup this will run the batch fle and hence the later access and macro and your function....

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, the issue I am having is with setting up the macro for it, So I create a macro select the RunCode Action and name the function Main and then save the macro as AutoExec. When I try and run the batch flle I get an error saying to exit and restart Microsoft Access using valid command-line options and then I get an error about it cant find the database .mdb.

Comment: This works thanks, sorry I needed to change my sub to a function

Answer (score 0):

Macros can only call functions, not subs. As @marlan said, can have code in load event of a form set to open by default and the optional arguments not needed. Another alternative is Windows Task Scheduler calls a script file which has code to open db, call VBA procedure, and close db. Here is structure of a VBScript executable (file extension .vbs).

```
Dim accessApp
set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("your path/filename here")
accessApp.Run "your procedure name here"
accessApp.Quit
set accessApp = nothing
```

Comment: Is the procedure name the Module name? sorry I don't really use access db and I am trying to work this out but its very confusing at the moment.

Comment: The 'procedure name' is the procedure name. Not a module name, as already noted by @marlan. But I see you have solution calling the AutoExec which calls the function procedure.